# visual studio c# - dynamic insertion of images via reference

Tags: c#, resources

I am getting more and more enthusiastic about programming with C# in Visual Studio and I am trying to finalize a quiz that I made, so that it's exportable.

I had a working version which referenced images dynamically to a static location, but I am struggling to adjust this to extract from the resources folder now. I hope someone can help me out.

1. I have buttons on my form, which set the string `categories` to a certain category (countries, flags, music) and the integer `imagecounter` to 0.
2. I have images named after the categories which then show up from that category when the quiz is started and cycle through it with the `imagecounter`.

```cs
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\\Users\\Thijs\\Desktop\\quiz-map\\" + categories + imagecounter + ".jpg";

imagecounter++;
```

This works perfectly fine, but sharing the solution with friends, I want it to pull the images from the resource file. I have added all images there, but am not able to cycle through the images in the same way:

```cs
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources. + category + imagecounter;
```

How can I make this work?

I can't seem to make use of the same reference to cycle through the images and tried some different ways of notation, but can't seem to find the way to make this happen.

Comment: The Resources class should have surfaced a ResourceManager class. So you can ask for resources by name. To get an understanding how that might work simply open the Resources.Designer.cs file you should have and take a closer look in the implementation of the properties you try to use here.

Comment: Hi Ralf, thank you very much for replying to my post! I may be a bit of a beginner and not fully understanding your explanation here. How do I "surface" a resourcemanager class? Sorry for my limited understanding.

Comment: I meant it has a ResourceManager property already. You can call `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager`. The ResoureManager has a GetObject method that takes the Resourcename as string. As i suggested already look at the sourcecode of your Resources class that will help immensely to understand how that works and can be used.

Comment: Got it to work properly now, thank you very much for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ralf's suggestions I managed to fix the above by using the following:

```cs
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(categories + imagecounter) as Image;
```

Thank you so much!